# Entity Framework Auto Migrations Primary Key

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have inherited a sql server database and an ASP.Net MVC 4 web application which is using **Entity Framework 5.0 Code First** with **Auto Migrations** . However, it appears the previous developer forgot to add a Primary Key to one of the tables. I am now trying to do this using **Auto Migrations**, however, it is not working, no errors either, just seems to be ignoring the command.

The table is like this

```
 public int CourseDateHistoryID { get; set; }
 public int CourseDateID { get; set; }
 public int Event { get; set; }
 //public string testProp{ get; set; }
```

And my mapping is like this to try and create the primary key on **CourseDateHistoryID**

```
this.HasKey(t => t.CourseDateHistoryID);

this.Property(t => t.CourseDateHistoryID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I thought maybe the connection string was wrong or something, so I tried to add a dumby string property called **testProp** using auto migrations, but this worked fine.

Would anyone have any ideas as to why I cannot set **CourseDateHistoryID** as the PK using auto migrations?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try manually updating the database using Update-Database -verbose command. It should show you the migration it's applying as well as the errors it encounters.

Or why not add another migration using the Add-Migration command and manually add primary key there, for example:

```
public partial class AddPrimaryKey : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddPrimaryKey(table: "dto.table", column: "CourseDateHistoryID", name: "PK_CourseDateHistoryID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey(table: "dto.table", name: "PK_CourseDateHistoryID");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.