# There is already an object named 'Beneficiarios' in the database

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, relational-database

[My database and migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdtMF.png)

There are my models I can't delete my migrations. It's necessary include the relation without delete the others migrations or delete my database.

Question: is there another way not create the table again?

I can delete the migration called `relacion`.

**Past Models:**

```
[Key]
        public  int beneficiarioId { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string apellidoBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string cedula { get; set; }
        public string resolucion { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficio { get; set; }
        public string siglas { get; set; }
        public string tipoBeca { get; set; }
        public string estado { get; set; }
        public int mesInicio { get; set; }
        public int anoInicio { get; set; }
        public int mesVence { get; set; }
        public int anoVence { get; set; }
        public int montoTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal montoOtorgado { get; set; }
        public decimal montoPendiente { get; set; }
        public string fuente { get; set; }
        public string codigoPlastico { get; set; }
        public string fotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string firmaUrl { get; set; }
        public bool impreso { get; set; }
        public string fechaImpreso { get; set; }

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

**Current models:**

```
[Key]
        public  int beneficiarioId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string apellidoBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string cedula { get; set; }
        public string resolucion { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficio { get; set; }
        public string siglas { get; set; }
        public string tipoBeca { get; set; }
        public string estado { get; set; }
        public int mesInicio { get; set; }
        public int anoInicio { get; set; }
        public int mesVence { get; set; }
        public int anoVence { get; set; }
        public int montoTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal montoOtorgado { get; set; }
        public decimal montoPendiente { get; set; }
        public string fuente { get; set; }
        public string codigoPlastico { get; set; }
        public string fotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string firmaUrl { get; set; }
        public bool impreso { get; set; }
        public string fechaImpreso { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Beneficiario> Beneficiarios { get; set; }
    }
```

**Past Migration:**

```
 public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Beneficiarios",
                c => new
                    {
                        beneficiarioId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        nombreBeneficiario = c.String(),
                        apellidoBeneficiario = c.String(),
                        cedula = c.String(),
                        resolucion = c.String(),
                        nombreBeneficio = c.String(),
                        siglas = c.String(),
                        tipoBeca = c.String(),
                        estado = c.String(),
                        mesInicio = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        anoInicio = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        mesVence = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        anoVence = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        montoTotal = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        montoOtorgado = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                        montoPendiente = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                        fuente = c.String(),
                        fotoUrl = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.beneficiarioId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.Beneficiarios");
        }
```

**Last Migration:**

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Beneficiarios",
                c => new
                    {
                        beneficiarioId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        nombreBeneficiario = c.String(),
                        apellidoBeneficiario = c.String(),
                        cedula = c.String(),
                        resolucion = c.String(),
                        nombreBeneficio = c.String(),
                        siglas = c.String(),
                        tipoBeca = c.String(),
                        estado = c.String(),
                        mesInicio = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        anoInicio = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        mesVence = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        anoVence = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        montoTotal = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        montoOtorgado = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                        montoPendiente = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                        fuente = c.String(),
                        codigoPlastico = c.String(),
                        fotoUrl = c.String(),
                        firmaUrl = c.String(),
                        impreso = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        fechaImpreso = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.beneficiarioId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Beneficiarios", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
            DropIndex("dbo.Beneficiarios", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropTable("dbo.Beneficiarios");
        }
```

Problem:

> There is already an object named 'Beneficiarios' in the database.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STRcj.png).

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but if you already have 'Beneficiarios' in the database and it's schema is correct, you can simply comment out the table creation from Up() and apply the migration. EF will now have it in the model and not try to create it in future migrations.

Comment: my question is very clear i think so...There is already an object named 'Beneficiarios' in the database.

Comment: You may want to change the title to reflect the problem. IAC, if migrations is trying to re-add an existing table it means the prior migration doesn't have that table in its metadata. Several workarounds for that, but since you indicate you don't want to delete the existing migrations, commenting out the redundant table creation code and applying the migration is one way.

Comment: doesn't works because i need to do the relation

Comment: Delete the current migration. Remove the relation from your model (or fluent code). Regenerate the migration. Comment out the Up() code and update-database. Add the relation back in and create a new migration to include it.

Comment: i don't know why doesn't recognizes the table beneficiarios @SteveGreene always create the table again

Comment: The way migrations work is that it compares the current migration to the prior migration. There is an XML model embedded that is used to compare. So if that table is not in the embedded model of the prior migration EF will try to create it. Has nothing to do with the database. So in my prior comment the idea is to get it into the embedded model in step 1, then in the next migration you can add the relation back in.

Comment: how can i put add primary key and add foreign key in this table? can you help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295662/entity-framework-auto-migrations-primary-key and add foreign key?

Comment: It looks like your models are correct in that EF is trying to add a PK and FK. Your issue is that it doesn't know the table already exists so your options are 1) Delete the table and let migrations add it back. 2) Get migrations to understand that the table exists before those changes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ito2307/q30z7xbw/1/ i put this!

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: well i have another question because i'm doing a query and say some error can i put here it?

Comment: I would add a new question and then add a comment with a link to that question here.